# Alternative way to scrape the data from this website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to scrape the odds for each game at https://www.oddschecker.com/us/football.  I do not see an obvious way to access any API when using the Chrome Tools XHR tab.  Am I missing something here?  Where is this data coming from?

I know I could scrape the data by loading the Javascript using Splash or Selenium (I am using Scrapy and python) but I am having major headaches with Splash that I can't seem to get any help with.  I was hoping someone could show me a way to access the API so I could skip using these ways to load dynamic websites.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see the page source, data in that website is loaded from a script variable with `id` `initial-data`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests, json

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
r = requests.get('https://www.oddschecker.com/us/football', verify=False, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
data = json.loads(soup.find("script", {"id":"initial-data"}).get_text(strip=True))

with open("data.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(data,f)
```

Comment: DUDE.  I wish I could give you a hug.  I am not sure how I was overthinking that.  Can you explain this line:

`with open("data.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(data,f)`

Also, what was your thought process here?  In your experience do you ever need something like Selenium if you aren't clicking/typing anything or logging in?

Comment: The line mentioned in your code, saves the json to the disk as a json file. It depends on how the website behaves.